# Find and delete cookie with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies

How would like to with javascript find a cookie that starts with 'AzureAppProxyAccess' and delete that cookie? It always has a series of random numbers at the end of the name. It is in the same domain so I have access to it.
This is what I have tried with jquery but I would like just javascript.

```
for (cookie in $.cookie()) {
    if(cookie.substring(0, 19) === "AzureAppProxyAccess") { 
        $.removeCookie(cookie);
    } 
};
```

Comment: you want pure js?why tag it wil jquery?

Comment: Use a regular expression

Comment: what would an regular expression look like?

Comment: Regular expression to find matching cookie can be `Boolean(cookie.match(/(AzureAppProxyAccess)/))` or probably more elegant way is `/AzureAppProxyAccess/.test(cookie)`

Answer (score 0):

You can use indexOf in strings.

```
cookie.indexOf('AzureAppProxyAccess') > 1 ? doSomething : somethingElse
```

Or, like it was said in one of the comments, use RegEx.

Comment: How would you select and delete that cookie though just with finding through indexof?